# Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Tags: swift

here is my code:

```
var cardArray2 = [[String:Any]]()
insertDataIntoEntity("DeviceEntity", cardArray2)
```

the following method call is yielding this error:

Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

here is my method signature:

```
func insertDataIntoEntity(_ entityTableName: String, _ arr: [String:Any]){
```

I tried to convert Any to Object, but that still did not work

Comment: `cardArray2` is a `[[String:Any]]` object (meaning: Array of Dictionaries which keys are String objects and values Any objects). Your method expect a `[String:Any]` object (which mean Dictionary which keys are String objects and values Any objects). You see that it's not the same right? And writing `_arr:`, so by reading we as developer expects the argument to be an Array, but the type is in fact a Dictionary.

Comment: The compiler message is quite clear here: embed in one set of brackets instead of two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change arr parameters to array of dictionary:

```
func insertDataIntoEntity(_ entityTableName: String, _ arr: [String:Any])
```

to

```
func insertDataIntoEntity(_ entityTableName: String, _ arr: [[String:Any]])
```

Comment: can you explain the difference ?

Comment: your cardArray2 is array of dictionary and your method take dictionary object, so you should change the method parameter to take array of dictionary